# Slick2D : translate -> scale -> translate doesn't return to the old position

Tags: graphics, slick

I am trying to implement zoom using Slick2D library.

As I understand, to zoom something on non (0,0) coordinates, we need:

- translate so the target point is in (0,0)
- apply scale factor
- translate the target point back from (0,0)

Code example :

```
 aGraphics.translate(-width/2, -height/2);
 aGraphics.scale(2,2);
 aGraphics.translate(width/2, height/2);
```

The issue is, as far I understand, that the scale factor is applied to the translation too. To compensate this, I have use the next code :

```
 aGraphics.translate(-width/2, -height/2);
 aGraphics.scale(2,2);
 aGraphics.translate(width/4, height/4);
```

Is this expected behaviour for graphics ? Can I workaround the above effect using push/pop matrix ?

Comment: After you scale your object by `scale`, your coordinates will be `scale` times bigger.
So try multiplying the offset by the scale factor, after the scale have been applied. `aGraphics.translate(offsetX*scaleX, offsetY*scaleY);`

Comment: Yep. You've adjusted the second translation backwards; you need to use `(width, height)` in the second one instead of `(width/4, height/4)`.

Comment: @NathanReed, could you please detail your answer? Yes - it's expected, or Yes - there is a workaround ?

Comment: @AndreiPodoprîgora I was agreeing with Gustavo's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that slick 2d doesn't consider the center coordinates when scaling. It just multiplies any coordinates using current scale.